# Backing up a SAN used for a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, storage, database-backups, san, lto

The scenario is basically an SQL Server Database stored on a SAN. I'm trying to implement a backup strategy for this SAN, as on this SAN will be stored the databases for the project.

The suggestion is to use Tape Backups, but I don't know how feasible it is or if this practice is obsolete. I would like to use a secondary SAN as a backup system, but I keep seeing the LTO tapes as the main suggestion for the emergency backup system. The goal is to make it as simple and quick to recovery as possible, having also maximum reliability for the storage solution used as backup.

Is this a correct approach? What is the most implemented backup system, taking in consideration that this will be a data warehousing project that will use SSIS to design the packages and these backups only will save the data.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: This is too broad and is about storage, not SQL Server. Backups on SQL Server should be asked on dba.stackexchange.com but an answer to this would depend on the SAN itself... specifically the vendor and what they support (SAN Snapshots, etc) and what other products you have in place, what other storage limitations, RPT and RTO, etc....

Comment: @scsimon I understand, sorry for asking on the wrong place. So in the end, the SAN implemented as main storage has to dictate the backup system? is it feasible to somehow "mirror" the main SAN?

Comment: There is software/hardware designed to replicate data to a "backup" SAN, yes. This site really isn't for recommendations, and this is not a recommendation, but an example would be Quest "Qorestor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an absolutely right approach. Enterprise SAN storage arrays have remote replication solutions (both synchronous and asynchronous) so you can roll your backup system and backup data from the remote array to LTO tapes on the secondary site with RPO/RTO you can tolerate. It's even possible to do backups in "LAN-less" and "Server-less" modes (see what technology is implemented in your storage systems and check if they applicable to you, because they can provide so called "image" backups, not individual file backups). The most of enterprise class backup solutions are aware of DB features like "begin/end backup state" requirements and etc. The one common issue with all these SAN/storage and backup solutions, they are usually not free.

Answer (score -1):

Backing up SQL Server databases should be done via a "SQL Server AWARE" application, not SAN replication.  SAN replication cannot guarantee the files are in sync and will likely give you corrupt data under high load.

You need to use a real backup application, either to tape or SAN storage.